# cloudformation does not seem to run ( or create ) the script in UserData

Tags: cloud-init, aws-cloudformation

I have something like this with in my cloudformation template

```
    "UserData": {
      "Fn::Base64": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "#cloud-config\n",
            "repo_releasever: ",
            {
              "Ref": "LinuxVersion"
            },
            "\n",
            "\n",
            "runcmd:\n",
            " - [curl, -s, -S, -o, /tmp/user_data.txt, 'http://some.s3bucket.amazonaws.com/cfn/some_Script.txt']\n",
            " - [bash, /tmp/user_data.txt]\n",
            " - [mkdir, -p, /root/.aws/\n",
            " - [echo, ' aws_access_key_id = ", { "Ref": "AWSAccessKey" }, " >> /root/.aws/credentials']\n",
            " - [echo, ' aws_secret_access_key' = ",  { "Ref": "AWSSecretAccessKey" },  " >> /root/.aws/credentials']\n"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Once the instance is provisioned by CloudFormation none if this is executed.

There is nothing created in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/.

I do see the script when I curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data

Answer (score 1):

I think that the first line of your UserData has to be `"#!/bin/bash\n",` to make it into a script that can run, so the first few lines of your code would be:

```
"UserData": {
  "Fn::Base64": {
    "Fn::Join": [
      "",
      [
        "#!/bin/bash\n",
        "#cloud-config\n",
        "repo_releasever: ",
```